# Issue with class return dealing with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to get my method name() to output the name.
When I call the method on an object of class Person, I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       a.name() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>   But if I simply type a (or whatever object I define to be of class Person), it is able to print the entered str in my repr class

```
import time
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name="[]", yearOfBirth=0):
        self.name = name
        self.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}:${}'.format(self.name, self.yearOfBirth)

    def age(self):
        a = time.localtime()
        output = a[0] - self.yearOfBirth
        return output
    def name(self,name):
        name = self.name
        return name
```

Comment: You're using the same identifier for the method and for the attribute.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at properties. Though this is not necessary for `self.name`.

Comment: `def name(self):
        return self.name` I changed it do this, but still wont return the string I enter initially at object declaration.

Comment: Always add `_` to private variable names, so something like: `def name(self): return self._name` and in `__init__` `self._name=name`